# Truncate target Table based on rows in a Target Flatfile

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have a workflow which loads data from a Flat file to a Stage Table after a few basic checks on a few columns. In the mapping, each time my check fails (meaning if the column has an invalid value) , I make an entry to a `ErrorFlatFile` with an `error text`.

Now , I have two targets in my mapping. One being the Stage table and the other is the Error Flat File.

What i want to achieve is this ? Even if there is one entry in the `ErrorFlatFile (indicating there is an error in the source file )` , I want to truncate the Target Stage Table.

Can someone Please help me with how i can do this at the session level.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You would need one more session. Make a dummy session (one that reads no data) and add a Pre or Post-SQL statement:

> TRUNCATE TABLE YourTargetStageTableName

Create a link from your existing session to the dummy one and add the condition like:

> $PMTargetName@numAffectedRow > 0

replacing `TargetName` with the name of your `ErrorFlatFileName`. The second session should only be executed in case when there was an entry made to the error file. If there will be no errors, it should not be executed.